# MySQL explain for DELETE queries

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to explain a `DELETE` query with MySQL like we can explain a `SELECT` query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wouldn't the plan for that be the same as for a `select 1 where....` with the same condition as your `delete` query?

The `1` is so the optimizer isn't forced to pull any unneeded columns, it can only look at the columns it needs for the filtering conditions.

Answer (score 39):

"As of MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information about SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE statements. Before MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information only about SELECT statements."

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not quite right.  A DELETE would also remove index entries from any associated indexes (mysql erroneously calls them 'keys').  There are also delete triggers to consider as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).